# Writing into a pipe in perl

Tags: perl, pipe

I am passing the commands to some application through the Perl script using the pipe.
So I write the commands on pipe. But my problem is that the pipe is not waiting till the command execution is over from the application side and it takes the next command. So it is not blocking the inputs till the command execution is over. I need my Perl script work like UNIX shell. But it happens like the process is running in to background. I use readling to read the inputs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Term::ReadLine;

open (GP, "|/usr/bin/gnuplot -noraise") or die "no gnuplot";
use FileHandle;
GP->autoflush(1);
# define readline
$term = new Term::ReadLine 'ProgramName';
while (defined( $_ = $term->readline('plot>'))) {
    printf GP ("$_\n");
}
close(GP);
```

Comment: I guess, the pipe must be closed after each command sent. not sure though.

Comment: please i do not want to close the pipe, but it should wait till the execution is over.

Comment: try [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use of a concrete CPAN module, like [Chart::Gnuplot](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Chart%3a%3aGnuplot), so you can have a high level of control

Comment: I am sorry, GNUPLOT is an example. The application may be something else, which will take few seconds for the execution of each command. And the pipe should be continuously open. The pipe will be closed when the entire operation is over. Problem is it takes the inputs, and do not wait for the execution of applicaton. Please help.